# Oxyplot Model Handle Key Press

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

OxyPlot's PlotModel and PlotController components contains their own Mouse Handlers, to which you can add or remove you own Handlers. For Instance:

```
this.Model.MouseMove += this.ModelOnMouseMove;

public void ModelOnMouseMove(object sender, OxyMouseDownEventArgs e)
{
    // Do some mouse stuff...
}
```

Is there a way for the Model to capture KeyBoard Key presses in a similiar manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OxyPlot apparently does have a Model.Keydown Even Handler, that triggers when the PlotModel is in focus. There just doesn't appear to be much documentation on it:

```
this.Model.KeyDown += ModelOnKeyDown;

private void ModelOnKeyDown(object sender, OxyKeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Key == OxyKey.Up)
     {
        // Do Some Stuff
     }
     else if (e.Key == OxyKey.Down)
     {
         // Do Some Stuff
     }
 }
```